# Text being updated in real time

Tags: php, javascript

I need some text to be updated in real time depending on choices from dropdown boxes.

Here's an example: http://www.thatsoftwareguy.com/swguy_demo_1.3.7/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=65&products_id=183

I know how to get an input box automatically updated, using the NAME and ID - but how do you give normal text a NAME and ID?

Comment: Just wrap the text in a <span /> tag with a suitable id so you can easily select it with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a span, give it an ID and then reference that ID and update the HTML inside

Answer (score 1):

To give the text an ID you should enclose it in a `<span></span>`.

So, you'd have `Price: <span id="price">3.00</span>$`.

**EDIT**

In order to operate with the price:

```
var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);
price += 5;
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price.toFixed(2);
```

This would increase the price by 5$. Allways make sure to validate anything you recive in the server side aswell though.

For the completness, I'll explain everything involved.

- `document` is a DOM element.
- `getElementById( id )` is a `document` function wich finds the first element with the given id.
- `innerHTML` For data wich can contain data inside, this contanins what is inside the data as an string.
- `parseFloat` converts an string to a floating point number.
- `toFixed(decimals)` is a float function wich makes the float an string with the given number of decimals.

Hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get the 3.00 to change. No matter what I select, it still just says 3.00. Where as if I use an input box: <input size="7" type="text" readonly="true" id="price" name="thirdBox"> it updates in real time.

Comment: You have to modify the .innerHTML property. `document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 25.00`

Comment: maybe you could add in a little javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container of the text an `id` and use `document.getElementById("theId").innerHTML` to modify the contents of that container.

The container could be a `div`, a `span` or a `p` element, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
 <div id="estimate" style="font-weight:
 bold; font-size: 14px;"> </div>
```

to display the pricelist like that use hidden filed ex:

```
 <input type="text" name="txthidden"
 id="txthidden" value="">
```

. through select box on change function paste the response text in both div and hidden field,

```
  document.getElementById('txthidden').value = responsetext;
```

then using normal php you can post the txthidden value.

Comment: Are you using ajax for refreshing the prize list